# Member gets member: granting points

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, email

My site has a recommend to a friend button.
To encourage people to use this functionality I want to reward those who use it with points (points will be redeemed for prizes .. don't know yet).

Ok, so I have this structure:

form.php

Here's where you enter your friend's email and a message to him/her if you want. Also there's a hidden input that will be sending your user id to action.php.

action.php

is where phpmailer does the magic and your message if any and a "visit my site" link (a link to process.php in my site containing your user id) is sent to your friend.

Your friend clicks the link and visits process.php

This file connects to my MySQL database table selects the points the user id sent has, adds 10 more points for the friend recommendation and insert the final points back to the table.
Then there's a :

```
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com");
```

so your friend does not see process.php working.

Everything is working great but for:
if your friend keeps clicking the link, he/she will earning points endlessly.

How can I fix that?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Do you mean by attaching a hash to the url and then storing that hash in a table and marking it as complete when done being processed? something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preferred method for making a process occur only once when they are clicking a link in an email is to have a table something like:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE friends (
>    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>    hash VARCHAR(100),
>    active TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
>    [user id's or other associative fields you want]
> ) TYPE=innodb;
> ```

then when i generate the url for email I'll attach a hash to the end so:

> ```
> http://my.url.com/process.php?hash=[hash]
> ```

and store the hash and relative info in the database then when they click the link I use the hash to pull the user id's and do any processing and change active from 1 to 0.

The next time they click the link you would pull the record and if active is set to 0 you just return a page that says "*You've already got the points you cheater*" :) or something more professional. (I've always wanted to call people out, but the powers that be always stop me)

Let me know if you need further explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Generate a unique token for every e-mail you send and include that token in the url/link inside the e-mail. Also store all the tokens in a database table. When someone clicks the link and visits your site, search for that token and mark it as visited. Only add the 10 points when the token wasn't already marked as visited.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep either the IP or the SessionID on file (perhaps in the database) and check every time someone votes.

If you keep the SessionID they will be able to vote again whenever they reopen the browser. If you keep the IP they will be able to vote again upon IP change, whichever fits your application.

This is how I would do it.

Comment: Not a voting system, but a refer-a-friend system